# Multiple file uploads with progress bar in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I want to upload multiple image files from local computer to web server with progress bar (and percentage completed).  How can I do this with asp.net?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out [jQuery Ajax uploader plugin (with progress bar!)](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/)...