# How to upload multiple files to server with form post MVC?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a project of Asp.Net MVC-4. In my project user post requirements. Post contains *title*, *tags*, *files* etc.File may be multiple and it may be of any type like Video, doc ( ppt, excel, pdf, etc), images etc.

My problem is the handling of multiple file upload. Now first of all i tell you

*currently how i am handling this* :

I am using [Jquery FIle Uplaod](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) plugin. Through this plugin i am uploading file to server sequentially and on server i am saving those file with **SessionId**.Now when user post there requirement form than i just rename those file with userId.

*drawback of my approach*

First i have to save those files with session id and than i have to rename it with userId. So if i save my file in Window Azure Blobs than in that case for uploading single file i have to do 2 transaction. First save the blob with SessionId and than Renaming the blob with userid. Which i think result extra processing and extra cost.

Now i want to know if there is any approach by which i can upload all file (**with progress bar for individual file [required]**) with form post. So that user's requirement form (tags, titile etc) with all files go to server together than in that case i will save the user first in the database and than i will save the files with the userId ??

**Note:** *I cannot save File with guid or other. UserId is required in the file name to uniquely identify user's files.*

Comment: I don't understand this question. You cant just rename the files with  userid? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This was answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284081/multiple-file-uploads-with-progress-bar-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

You can upload using following code in controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files) {
  foreach (var file in files) {
    if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
      var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
      var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
      file.SaveAs(path);
    }
  }
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

more details [here](http://programmers.bhoomijunction.com/Article/Uploading-posting-multiple-files-simultaneously-in-one-shot-in-MVC-DOT-NET-25)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i completely understand the question, but you could post the model for your user details in the same POST as the file upload (same form?), then on the server:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddNewImage(UserModel user)
    {
        ReturnArgs r = new ReturnArgs();
        repo.AddUser(user) // add your user to DB here

        SaveImages(user.Id);
        r.Status = 200;
        r.Message = "OK!";

        return Json(r);
    }

    private void SaveImages(string userid)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[i] as HttpPostedFileBase;
            string fileName = userid + "_" + i;

            // saving file to DB here, but you can do what you want with
            // the inputstream

            repo.SaveImage(fileName, file.InputStream, file.ContentType);
        }
    }
```